# Windows azure MVC website not displaying any HTML

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, azure, model-view-controller

I've recently uploaded this MVC ASP.Net 4.5 site to windows Azure: http://oncohub.azurewebsites.net which works perfectly well locally, but as you can see by going to the link the page doesn't display anything. Even if I check the source there isn't anything. The aren't any errors showing either.

The thing is that it is redirecting to the correct view/page url, so it seems that the code is behaving correctly.

Is this a common problem?

Comment: As far as i can see, the site redirects you to a login url, but doesn't respond. I guess that there's no connection to a database.

Comment: Wouldn't I see a connection error though?

Comment: Turn on Remote Debugging in the control panel and step through the code to see what's happening http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/05/remote-debugging-a-window-azure-web-site-with-visual-studio-2013.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for that Brent, I've installed the sdk on visual studio 2013, but when i right click on the website to attach the debugger I don't see the option. Not sure if maybe it's because it's the free account?

Comment: Found out that I needed to enable remote debugging in the configure section of the website on azure first. I'll let you know how I get on

Comment: So after enabling debug I was able to find out the the site code was checking a table to see if the url I was accessing the site from existed in the table, which of course it didn't so threw a wobbly lol